# What is meant by the language of a Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines

So I tried searching for the precise definition of language, but all articles assume that the definition is obvious to everyone. Apparently, to me it isn't.

What is the definition of a Turing machine's language?

Comment: This is probably better asked on Computer Science.SE or Theoretical Computer Science.SE.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run a TM, you give it as input a string. The TM will then either accept the string, reject the string, or loop on the machine. The language of a TM is defined as the set of all the strings it accepts.

Not every language is the language of a Turing machine - that's one of the landmark results of theoretical computer science. The languages that are languages of Turing machines have lots of names - they're the *Turing-recognizable languages*, the *semi-decidable* languages, and the *recursively enumerable languages*. You'll see all these terms used depending on the context.